# how can i do to export layers from Esri with python

Tags: python, list, join, arcpy

i try to join a text (an adress) with a list to have at final my list with the adress in fisrt like:
paris street 1
paris street 2
etc
so i try to do that with this script, but it' dont work .

Can you help me?

```html
targetPattern=r"C:\Users\**\AppData\Roaming\Esri\ArcGISPro\Favorites"
target = glob.glob(targetPattern)
print (target)
joiend = [target,Rezo]

for ready in joiend:
# JOIN TARGET
ready = (''.join([''.join(target),r'\Rezo_h@geom06.sde\rezo_h.geom04.REGIE_EAU_POTABLE']))

print (ready)

arcpy.env.workspace = ready
#list adress

fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("rezo_h.geom04.AEP*")

print (fcs)

jointure = List.insert(ready, fcs)

for ready2 in jointure:
# JOIN TARGET
ready2 = fcs.join(ready)

print ("jointure")
print (ready2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to solve my problem i use

```html
x = [1, 2, 3]

y = ["t" + str(i) for i in x]

y
['t1', 't2', 't3']
```

and it work